# Is There a Way to Replication Maven attachClasses war Plugin Functionality in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Using Maven we are currently separating out classes from a WAR file using:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to replicate this functionality in Gradle? The goal is to publish just the classes in a .jar alongside the primary war artifact:

```
ghc-templates-2.29-javadoc.jar       14-Jan-2014 15:19  112.43 KB
ghc-templates-2.29-sources.jar       14-Jan-2014 15:19  12.81 KB
ghc-templates-2.29.war               14-Jan-2014 15:19  6.05 MB
ghc-templates-2.29-classes.jar       14-Jan-2014 15:19  23.95 KB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just run `jar` task. Since the `War` plugin applies the `Java` plugin you get all the regular tasks you would as if it were a normal java project. However, that task is not included in the dependency graph by default when running `assemble` (see the [grade docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html)). To fix this simply add:

```
assemble {
    dependsOn jar
}
```

Also, as per your example above, if you want to add a custom classifier to the jar you can do so:

```
jar {
    classifier = 'classes'
}
```