# Gradle jar generation

Tags: java, jar, gradle, build.gradle

When war plug-in is enabled in build.gradle, jar generation is automatically disabled. Is it possible to fix it or does it require splitting the project into two projects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is There a Way to Replication Maven attachClasses war Plugin Functionality in Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535885/is-there-a-way-to-replication-maven-attachclasses-war-plugin-functionality-in-gr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do:

```
assemble.dependsOn (jar)
```

anywhere in the file. The WAR plugin simply doesn't include the task by default

Comment: The war plugin does not *disable* the `jar` task, it just simply isn't executed by default when doing something like `gradle build`.

Comment: Why the down-vote? I added an edit addressing exactly this situation.

Comment: The first part of your answer is incorrect and not applicable to Tad's question. I'd suggest removing everything prior to your edit.